# Can I delete the files the user Pick with file-picker?

Tags: flutter, dart, filepicker

I need to let the user pick files from his device then I need to delete the picked files.
All I can access from the FilePickerResult is the path for the cached files not the actual path in the external storage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can delete files . Access the file from path and use this method.

```
Future<void> fileDelete(File file) async {
try {
   if (await file.exists()) {
    await file.delete();
   }
  } catch (e) {
  print(e);
 }
}
```

Hope you have added necessary permissions in manifest.

Comment: File picker pickFiles method returns FilePickerResult? which doesn't have the actual path in for the file or a delete method.

Comment: FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

if (result != null) {
  File file = File(result.files.single.path);
} else {
  // User canceled the picker
}

Comment: This is the file's path in the cache not the actual path in the device, I want the actual path to delete the file from the external storage.

Comment: Without reference to the original file it wouldn't be possible to delete it